# ext4, btrfs, zfs and Ubuntu's future in 2017

Tags: ext4, btrfs, zfs

It's two years later (than [Does Ubuntu plan to move to btrfs as default filesystem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572911/does-ubuntu-plan-to-move-to-btrfs-as-default-filesystem)).  Ubuntu is at 16.10 and we are about to celebrate 2017.  (And there is also a ZFS wrench in the Canonical gears now.)

How much longer will ext4 remain the default file system? What will succeed it and when?

Comment: IMHO for the foreseeable future. If you are looking for newer answers to an old duplicate question, SOP would be to offer a bounty on it asking for more current answers. As is, this question is a duplicate of the one you linked....

Comment: To my knowledge LVM+EXT4 has succeeded the plain EXT4 default setup, here is the latest discussion on the mailing list I'm aware of: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2016-November/039538.html I have not followed this topic closely though.

Comment: the two-year old answer is obviously obsolete.  if someone asked about AI in 1975, the same answer may no longer be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are, ext4 will remain the default file system for a while.

I say this mostly because of precedent. Ubuntu tends to change very little 'under the hood' unless a major change is made in Debian Unstable, which Ubuntu is based on. (Example: The move from Upstart to SystemD)

Chances are unless Debian adopts btrfs as it's default filesystem, which most likely isn't going to happen anytime soon, ext4 will remain the default file system for a long time.